# How to debug JavaScript modules using the browser console?

Tags: javascript, module

I am using my JavaScript file as a module:

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

but, when my HTML is loaded, any object inside the `main.js` is not accessible from the browser debugging console, saying that the variable is not defined.

*main.js*:

```
var MyVar = 10;
```

[image]

When putting a breakpoint in `main.js` I can access the objects fine. But then the program is stopped, and I want to manipulate some while everything is running.

How can I access (global) objects in the JavaScript files I have included as `module`?

Comment: Try adding next line of code and put breakpoint there and then try console logging when the debugger reaches the breakpoint

Comment: "*How can I access (global) objects in the JavaScript files I have included as module?*" - they are **not global**, that's the whole point of modules. You could expose a few objects by assigning them to global variables, would that help? Or do you really need to execute arbitrary code in the module scope?

Comment: @Bergi both could work for me now (at least to get a better grasp on the whole module thing). I tried exposing objects, but didn't find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the breakpoint in the module, then when the program is stopped, [inspect the scope](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/#scope) to find the object that you are looking for, then [right-click and *store as global variable*](https://blittle.github.io/chrome-dev-tools/sources/store-as-global.html). Even after continuing execution, the object will be available in the global scope under that variable. You can also do this manually by putting an assignment `window.myGlobal = interestingObject` either directly in the module code or enter it in the console while stopped at a breakpoint.